# How do I save one piece of data in two databases using OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, postgresql-9.1

When I want to edit code in OpenERP, is it possible to save one piece of data in two databases where the fields have the same names in both tables.

Comment: What are u actually trying to do??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible if you know the database but let me warn you this is very bad idea cause it is very risky and all rule of Resistance layer (ORM) will be violated.

Comment: ow...really. I'll tell you my plan. This is my plan, I want to pull data in the SO and bring in new form. any ideas?

Comment: Well if you have database name then you can poll the database cursor like this  `pooler.get_db(db).cursor()`.
 then 
`cr.commit()`
`cr.rollback()`
`cr.close()`

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do?? If you are trying to synchronize, then use the module `base_synchro`. The module is not complete. You have to do your own customization in that module