# save data from sales order database to new database

Tags: odoo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I save one piece of data in two databases using OpenERP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424880/how-do-i-save-one-piece-of-data-in-two-databases-using-openerp)

sorry about my last question

I want make like this. If I clicked button save, sales order SO001 in SO database, stored into new a database. there is my script

```
def _product_search (self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg):


    cr.execute = ('SELECT sale_order.name FROM sale_order WHERE name = \'SO001\'')
    res = cr.fetchall()
```

but the script above, there is no response to anything, I really need your help, please

Comment: this is pretty much the same question....

Comment: can you give me answer, please or give me the link

Answer (score 0):

use the base_synchro module if you only want to synchronize the sale order in draft state only

Comment: how to use it ? so many field